# Filling NA s when using pd.merge

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames and I want to merge them on common columns as seen below. There is also a new column in the second data frame.

```
dummy_data1 = {'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],'name': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G'],
           'year':['2012','2012','2012','2012']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data1, columns = ['id', 'name', 'year'])

dummy_data2 = {
    'id': ['1', '2', '3', '7',],
    'name': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'P'],
    'ADDRESS': ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'P'],'year':['2013','2013','2013','2013']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data2, columns = ['id', 'name','ADDRESS','year'])
```

when I merge these two data frames with

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['name','id','year'],how='outer')
```

I get NaN s for some rows because of the newly added column, as expected:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqFjX.png)

My question is about the NaN s, is there a way to just repeat the data for the NaN if the data for that id is available in the other data frame. So for index 0, it brings 'X' instead of the NaNs, for index 1, 'Y' and so forth. I just want to assume that 'Address' for different years doesn't change.
Thanks!

Comment: please show an example sample of what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [pandas merge ordered](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_ordered.html) and use a [backward fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html?highlight=bfill#pandas.DataFrame.bfill)
merge ordered works for sorted data; as such, I would advise before using it to sort the data. In your case, it already is.

```
pd.merge_ordered(df1,df2).bfill()

    id  name    year    ADDRESS
0   1   A   2012         X
1   1   A   2013         X
2   2   C   2012         Y
3   2   C   2013         Y
4   3   E   2012         Z
5   3   E   2013         Z
6   4   G   2012         P
7   7   P   2013         P
```